# How do you make reusable/template charts in c3js

Tags: javascript, charts, reusability, c3

I'm trying to use C3.js(c3js.org) to make charts, but I want to specify everything but the data(and any other minor deviations unique to that chart) once then reuse that for all charts of that variation(a specific configuration of a chart).

All the documentation and all examples I've found for C3.js only deal with how you make a single chart. Applying that to multiple charts means a lot of repeated code and doesn't ensure consistency when making changes.

The only thing related to this that I've found is a [concept on making reusable charts](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/) in D3.js(d3js.org), the underlying library used by C3.js, and an [implementation](http://misoproject.com/d3-chart/) inspired by that concept. That doesn't really help me because I want the higher-level abstraction that C3.js provides but these may give you an idea what I'm looking for.

I have found no info on this but one idea is to make a chart type that is based on an existing type but that also include the extra configuration(for example make a new chart type called 'horizontalbar' based on the existing 'bar' chart type).

Here is a chart I've made, `bindto` and `columns` are the unique parts of this chart, the rest should be part of a template, but I don't know how.

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
 bindto: '#chart',
data: {
    columns: [
        ['data1', 125.2],
        ['data2', 282.7],
        ['data3', 3211.1],
        ['data4', 212.2],
        ['data5', 131.1], 
        ['data6', 329.7]
    ],
    type: 'pie',
    order: null
},
pie: {
    label: {
        format: function (value, ratio, id) {
            return d3.format('.1f')(ratio*100)+'%'; //percent with one decimal
        }
    }
},
tooltip: {
    format: {
        value: function (value, ratio, id, index) {
            return value+'mkr ('+d3.format('.1f')(ratio*100)+'%)'; //example: 155.2mkr (3.3%)
        } 
    }
},
legend: {
    item: {
        onclick: function () {} //disable clicking to hide/show parts of the chart
    }
}
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.9/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.9/c3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Why can't you save a chart as a template. That's what I did. If I want one like the template I've made, I copy the chart to a new folder, give it a new name, drop new data in, and that's it. CSS, everything already done.

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my html:

```
<script src="../static/js/test.js"></script> <!-- this is the js file contains the drawChart function --> 

<div class='chart'>
    <div id='chart1'></div>
</div>
<script>drawChart('chart1','pathToCsvData',ture, 200);</script>
```

in my js code:

```
function drawChart(toChart,dataURL,showLegend,chartHeight)
{   
    var chart1 = c3.generate({
        bindto: toChart,
        data: {
            url: dataURL,
            labels: false
        },
        color: {pattern: ['green','black']},
        zoom: {enabled: false},
        size: {height: chartHeight},
        transition: {duration: 0},
        legend: {show: showLegend}
    });
}
```

the js code serve as a template, and I can as many different template I want, put them in functions, with customized chart parameters, and the call the js function in html code.